# Does template use in C++ require some task initialization?

Tags: kernel, c++

Before being able to use some features of C++ for kernel development, some work has to be done. For example, to be able to use classes effectively, routines must be made to call constructors and destructors property.

Other features that aren't needed can be disabled, for example RTTI (run-time type information).

Is any additional work needed to be done to be able to use templates, assuming that classes are working properly?

Comment: Probably Torvalds would very much like to give you some jail time for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the main problem is writing the runtime code to walk the stack for exception handling.  The kernel and the compiler need to agree on details of the calling convention, like the structure of the stack, and how destructors get registered, discovered and invoked.

And if you want to support exception handling, then you (essentially) have to enable RTTI, because the C++ `catch` semantics do dynamic type matching.

Another problem might be memory allocation.  `new` maps to `malloc` quite naturally, but if you have a weird `kmalloc` with extra parameters (like Linux does) then it might require some thought.

Templates, and placement of calls to constructors and destructors (aside from exception handling) are dealt with entirely by the compiler, so should "just work."

Comment: Yes, I think operator overloading should "just work".  And if your kernel is using the same calling convention that user-level is using, then getting the exceptions working might not be too hard either.  In gcc I _think_ (but am not sure) that the relevant library for system-dependent runtime stuff is the `libsupc++` subset of `libstdc++-v3`.

Comment: Also important in linker scripts (if using exception handling) not to discard the eh_frame